# Chrome extension, how to delay script until page is fully loaded

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, dom, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to get a DOM element by class name just after opening new website address in the tab. The problem is that I have no idea how to make it wait until the page is fully loaded. I tried alarms, setTimeOut, setTimeDelay and nothing works.

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(message);

function message(msg) {
  chrome.tabs.update({url: 'https://www.website.com/'});
  chrome.tabs.executeScript({code:"var theBtn = document.getElementsByClassName('btn1');theBtn[0].click();"});
}
```

I am using chrome.runtime.sendMessage in the popup because I want to send web addresses from input, then I press a button and the code above is triggered. I simplified this because everything else works. The (msg) is just a website address

Comment: Very interesting question! It's been a while I Chrome Extensioned. ([It's Firefox' Extension too these days.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Anatomy_of_a_WebExtension#Background_scripts)) Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update:**

That won't work, because `executeScript` won't have a tab to execute on, because you just killed (updated) that. You'll have to split it into Background and Content script:

1. Background runs `chrome.tabs.update`
2. Background sends exact target URL to Content
3. Content listens on EVERY URL, but ignores all, unless it just got this exact URL from Background
4. If so, Content runs the script, (or tells Background to run `executeScript`, but that seems silly), forgets the URL, and goes back to idling

Maybe the communication in 2-3 must go the other way: Content asks Background for EVERY page load if it should act on this URL.

Very interesting use case! [I made a Proof of concept because it's X-mas!](https://gist.github.com/rudiedirkx/1e739b4ed65c5a879710461c92e674bf)

**Original:**

Untested! Two options:

2. Add a `load` listener wrapper in the script:

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript({
  code:"window.addEventListener('load', function() { var theBtn = document.getElementsByClassName('btn1');theBtn[0].click(); });"
});
```

That's your code, wrapped inside `window.addEventListener('load', function() { ... });`. Adding the event listener is executed immediately, but the code inside only when the page is loaded.

1. Use `executeScript`'s `runAt` option. I think you want `document_end`. [See docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript)

Actually it looks like the default (`document_idle`) is more suited: "the browser chooses a time between "document_end" and immediately after window.onload" ([from here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#run_at))

Comment: the function code wrapped inside window.addEventLisnter never runs, also runAt inside executeScript doesn't really work, I also tried runAt in the manifest file with no success. hmm, could the fact that my js file is set to run in the background be the problem?

Comment: `chrome.tabs.executeScript` must be run by a background script. Does none of the code run, or just not the onload? The listener must be added before it's executed (duh), so you must tell `executeScript` to be faster (`document_end` should do it).

Comment: I think `executeScript` runs too fast, before the tab even starts loading. You have to split the actions: `chrome.tabs.update` in the background script, and a content script to listen for every page load, and messages between them to know which page load is the one from the background script. - https://gist.github.com/rudiedirkx/1e739b4ed65c5a879710461c92e674bf works because there's no page load.

Comment: just quick note, if there is no tabId it will default to focused tab

Comment: I see. I didn't see any tab context in your minimal code. `browserAction.onClicked`? I made a POC, see answer.

Comment: You might want to use 'DOMContentLoaded' instead of 'load' – 'load' waits for all stylesheets and images to fully load, whereas 'DOMContentLoaded' only waits for the page to be loaded and parsed

Comment: "until the page is fully loaded" sounded like `onload` to me, but to find and click a button, that's indeed not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

there are three way to do this 
1. using run_at="document_end" in Manifest.json (ideal developers should use this one if possible)
2. using document is ready event using java-script or jquery
3. using executeScript